# wp_remote_post empty $_POST

Tags: php, http-api, wp-remote-post

Ok, I've searched a lot but cannot understand what I'm missing.
I need to post some data to a php file on another server,
but if I print the wp_remote_post variable I get:

```
{"headers":{},"body":"","response":{"code":200,"message":"OK"} .....
```

here the code:

```
        $url  = 'https://xxx.domain.net/api/api.php';
    $args = array(
            'method'      => 'POST',
            'timeout'     => 45,
            'sslverify'   => false,
            'headers'     => array(
                    'Authorization' => 'xxxx',
                    'Content-Type'  => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            ),
            'body'        => json_encode($attachment_fields),
            'data_format' => 'body'
    );
    $request = wp_remote_post( $url, $args );
```

and $attachment_fields is an array built previously.

It seems that it sends it out (it says code 200) but in the php file the $_REQUEST (or $_POST) is empty...
Sorry if is a stupid question but I'm struggling on it for a while..

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
found the problem: I didn't have to json_encode the body.